# Child elements invisible in Microsoft Edge when parent revealed with jQuery slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-edge

We have a page which works perfectly on all of the modern browsers EXCEPT for a couple of strange behaviors on Microsoft Edge only. Here is the URL:

http://www.oru.edu/online/

Scroll down to the section below "Earn a Fully Accredited Online Degree..." and click one of the photos or one of the degree names. Expected behavior is for a "details" section to slide down and the window to scroll down to it using jQuery's "slideDown" followed by "animate". The animations work well in all tested browsers.

The details section that comes down should contain a description of the degree on the left, and four rectangular clickable areas on the right: "Program Description", "Benefits of Degree", "Occupational Outlook", and "Degree Plan". Also, the background of the details areas should contain a blurred-out version of the picture you may have clicked to open it up.

All of the jQuery animations (slideDown, slideUp, animate, etc.) work in MS Edge, but when the details area slides down, sometimes (randomly, it seems) one or more of the four clickable rectangles does not appear until you hover the mouse over it.

Also at unpredictable intervals, the background image will only show behind part of the div, with the rest of it being a solid blue color.

I've tried changing the order of the jQuery events, I've researched possible changes to the CSS, I've tried it on two completely separate Windows 10 machines, and I can't seem to find anything that causes this to change in the least.

Thanks for any solutions or ideas!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I may have a solution regarding the scrolling issue in jQuery. No promises, but I did have a similar problem as yours once with an auto scrolling issue working in every browser except one. The fix was so tiny that I couldn't believe that one thing was causing such a big problem.

Without seeing your jquery code, I don't know if this the actual solution, but here goes...

Do you have a section of code in the animation portion of your jquery that looks anything like this?

```
$("html body").animate({
  scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
}
```

Of course, your code may not start with that "html body" or have "scrollTop" as the exact terms, but here is the point.

There needs to be a comma in between where the "html body" section of code is. In other words, like this...

```
$("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $("#" + sectionID).offset().top
}
```

As I said, your code may be pointing to different divs or elements of your website than my code example is showing, but the concept holds true.

That little comma may be what's keeping your animation from working in Edge. That is what happened to me. In a site I was building I initially didn't have the comma and it worked in EVERY browser I could throw at it, except for Edge. I spent a week on the issue!!!! Finally, I stumbled upon a forum that mentioned the comma and BAM it worked!

Give it a try and please report your results. Good luck!

Comment: I do have a line almost like that one, but sadly the comma is already there. The animations themselves are all working - it's just that once the parent div scrolls into view, sometimes some of the child elements are missing until you mouse over them. Once you mouse over them, the styles from the CSS seem to take over and the rectangles become visible.